# Can I click to get to a method/object in Sublime Text like I can in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am switching over from netbeans to Sublime Text 2. One of the features I really love in NetBeans is if you hit ctrl+Left Click (Yes I am using Windows) on a call to an object or method it will open the file with the object/method and go straight to the object/method. Is there a way to do this in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel - Never tried it myself, but it might be worth a shot

Comment: Not out of the box, no. Sublime is a text editor and not an IDE. There are however many plugins, they could be your best bet.

Comment: @AlexP really? sorry for my bad advice. so what do they call "Jump to Symbol Definition" then?

Comment: No @Pascamel, my apologies, your right. Looks like i'm using a different plugin. Apparently, it does!

Comment: oh ok @AlexP no problem ! JoeyD473, please give us a feedback if you give it a try. I might be interested too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just started using Sublime Text3 and have also been using NetBeans.

As Pascamel mentioned in the above comment, this is your best bet: https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel

You can install the Sublime Text Package Control, and then can install each plugin directly from Sublime and they will be kept up to date automatically by Package Control. https://sublime.wbond.net/

Note: If you can't find the package then you may have to Choose "add repository" from the package control and paste the Git url. After you do this, you can go to "Install package" from package control and you will then you will be able to find the plugin for the repo you just added.

Comment: your last paragraph is incorrect. Once Package Control has been installed, just go to `Package Control: Install` and search for your plugin of interest. No additional repositories are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I revised my response to only do the "add repository" step if it cannot be found as I did have to do this on my setup to find the package. Perhaps this question can now be closed.

Comment: CodeIntel is the plugin I needed. I'm still playing with it so not 100% if it is exactly what I want, but it seems to work so far

Answer (score 0):

I get Dash for your needs.

You can find more introduction about dash in [kapeli](http://kapeli.com/dash) site.

It's my first paied-app in Mac. Besides Sublime Text Dash can be supportive to Textmate, Eclipse and other editor or IDEs.

You can try its demo version for now.

Comment: I'm not using a mac so it wouldn't help

Answer (score 0):

To access a class with Sublime Text 3 and SublimeCodeIntel just **Alt + Click** on the Class Name.

See also here:

https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#using