# How to Access a Class through "Ctrl+Click" in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've got this class as an example:

Which plugin do I use to be able to click on:

**PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase**

And get to the class?

```
class PracticeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testHelloWorld() {
        $greeting = 'Hello, World.';
        $this->assertTrue($greeting === 'Hello, World.');
    }
}
```

Right now I have to manually search for it. I know PHPStorm has this functionality and I believe Sublime must have a plugin for it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate, the answer to your question has been given here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18721014/1125161

Answer (score 4):

Click on class name that you want to jump and press <kbd>f12</kbd>.

Comment: how do you jump to a class which is in another file

Answer (score 3):

Avalance pointed in the comments to a threat that hinted to **SublimeCodeIntel**.

And indeed SublimeCodeIntel allows for the behaviour I needed:

See here: 
https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel#using

The solution to **jump to definition** is this:

For Mac OS X:

```
Jump to definition = Control+Click
Jump to definition = Control+Command+Alt+Up
Go back = Control+Command+Alt+Left
Manual Code Intelligence = Control+Shift+space
```

For Linux:

```
Jump to definition = Super+Click
Jump to definition = Control+Super+Alt+Up
Go back = Control+Super+Alt+Left
Manual Code Intelligence = Control+Shift+space
```

For Windows:

```
Jump to definition = Alt+Click
Jump to definition = Control+Windows+Alt+Up
Go back = Control+Windows+Alt+Left
Manual Code Intelligence = Control+Shift+space
```